# Finding out if items chosen from a random pool could overlap

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Say that we have a big list of tagged items, lets call this the pool:

```
const poolList = [[low, med], [low], [low], [low, med], [high, med]];
```

This list is often shuffled at runtime, and typically things I call `stubs` pool from this list. `stubs` just need to feature in one of the `poolList` for that item to be chosen.

```
const stubs = [[low], [low], [med], [high]];
```

For some better scene setting, let's imagine this is a quiz game where when the player encounters a "stub", they are then pointed to the corresponding item on the `poolList`.

Once an item is chosen, it is **exhausted** from the `poolList`. My issue is that I need to know whether or not my `stubs` could possibly exhaust **all** of the poolList by way of unfortunate overlapping/choices. So what I tried doing, to devise a way to test this, is to do a "worst case" run, with the definitions provided before, I am iterating over `stubs`. Note that its "worst" because I am trying to find `poolList` items that feature 2 or more items (if for example stub `low` chose the singular `low` item, then then we are happy, but there is no guarantee it would choose that as runtime is random!). And remember, choosing them exhausts them from the pool (the entire item is dumped out). Below is a "test" that will fail (which is what we want).

1. First stub is `[low]`, I simply just choose `[low, med]` and remove that from the pool (that is the worst choice I can make)
2. Another `[low]`, grab `[low, med]`
3. `[med]` grab the last item `[high, med]`
4. uh oh, `[high]` is not on the `poolList`, panic!

However, as I mentioned before, the `poolList` is variable and always random. Here is an example where my "test" would be flaky (well, flakier than usual)

Given:

```
const badPoolList = [
  [low, med],
  [low, high],
  [wc, med],
  [high, med]
];
```

If we start iterating this in order, choosing the worst options possible, it's apparent that when I hit the stub `med`, I will have 2 "worst" choices to choose from (because the list will always come in shuffled). So there is a chance that *sometimes* we end with a success, and sometimes with a failure (ie, poolList does not contain the item we want), depending on order.

I've scratched a sort of "test bed" with some ideas on how to solve this here:
https://codepen.io/parthianshotgun/pen/JjBoxQv

However I find myself reaching for permutation or heaps algorithm, but that seems crazy since I would be doing `n!` iterations just to find the "one bad choice" that leads us to an exhausted pool. I wonder if I'm even framing this correctly, and am curious if there is a set theory/elegant way to weed out a faulty pool/stub combination.

Comment: What's the upper limit of the number of items in poolList and stubs?

Comment: Is there a limit to tags per item? It seems you are interested in at most two

Comment: There are no upper limits

Comment: When you say you iterate over poolist, you mean you can actually scan the list to find a match? Or you always pick the first one?

Comment: In game, the poolList is always shuffled at the start. So in essence my tests have to potentially cover every possibility deterministically. I just picked the first instance of the duplicate item as an example. So yeah, in game what's happening is that it scans for first instance of the matched pool item and picks that, with no regard for if it can possibly be the 'worst choice'.

Comment: Ok. So poollist has generated values and they are the same during the game (only shuffled and get reduced) and you can iterate over it. And you can also iterate over your stub. It means you can always determine how many is left for every value, right?

Comment: @SergeyAn Yes exactly, and with that in mind I could permute, but it would be `n!` to compute which could get expensive.

Comment: I just don't understand why you need to permute? Isn't keeping frequency of values in poollist enough?

Comment: we could keep frequency, but at runtime we are iterating and depleting the pool. Therefore frequency can be misleading. A freq of `stubs` is `low: 2, med: 1, high: 1` and the `badPoolList` is `low: 2, med: 3, high: 2, wc: 1`. If I compare both, it misleads us into thinking we are safe, ignoring the diminishing nature of `poolList`

Comment: Actually I have another question, why can't you just check if your element from stub is present in the poolList before you try to do any operation?

Comment: That is what I do, and again, it can say that the element is there, but the issue really arises when we have overlapping choices to make. The first stub needs to choose a pooled item, and that "choice" can vary and can sometimes deplete our pool. I edited the original post to make that point clear, hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two solutions, both of which I think are inelegant come to mind:

1. To determine if the `poolList` can *ever* be exhausted by virtue of its combinations (see `badPoolList` example above). I run [Heaps algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) on it, and then, in order, "choose" the first item that matched a `stub`. Doing so I can find when the thing fails, eventually. This is a factorial issue though, as the `poolList` grows, so does my run time and cost. I find this solution slightly inelegant but can't say why.
2. Impose an artificial heuristic. Make it so that `poolList` must ALWAYS have a paired single tag that matches to stubs. So no matter what, ignoring all overlapping etc, each `stub` needs a corresponding, single item. So for

```
const stubs = [[low], [low], [med], [high]];
```

I *need* my array to hold singly tagged items, at a minimum equal to the number of stubs

```
const poolList = [[low, med], [low], [low], [med], [high], [low, med], [high, med]];
```

This will ensure that even in the worst of worst cases, we never run out of pooledItems to draw from, no matter the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood so far:

If you generated stub from the poolList, it means that at the **initial** state
every element in stub should be **present** in poolList as there was no matching/depliting yet.

Now you start to match and deplete.

Say, you found the first element from stub in the poolList and you deleted this element from poolList. With that element you also deleted some other element that was **paired with** (overlapping) the first one.

Next you want to match another element from stab which happens to be the one that was paired and removed along with the first one you removed from the poolList.

Possible solution:

What you can do is **maintain** the **frequency** of the values in the poolList.

Initial state of poolList:

```
const badPoolList = [
  [low, med],
  [low, high],
  [high, med]
  [wc, med],
];
```

The frequency array or hashtable:

```
freq = [
"low": 2,
"med": 3,
"wc": 1,
"high": 1
];
```

Now, suppose you have a stub:

```
const stubs = [[low], [low], [med], [high]];
```

1. First element to match is "low".
2. We look at the frequency table and see that we have 2 of them (> 0).

If > 0 then deplete first match [low, med].

```
const badPoolList = [
  [low, high],
  [high, med]
  [wc, med],
];
```

Update frequency table:

```
freq = [
"low": 1, // Decrease this one
"med": 2, // AND this one was paired, so decreasing it 
"wc": 1,
"high": 2
];
```

Repeat for second match:

1. Second element to match is "low".
2. We look at the frequency table and see that we have 1 of them (> 0).

If > 0 then deplete first match [low, high].

```
const badPoolList = [
  [high, med]
  [wc, med],
];
```

Update frequency table:

```
freq = [
"low": 0, // Decrease this one
"med": 2,
"wc": 1,
"high": 1 // AND this one is also decreased
];
```

Repeat for third match:

1. Third element to match is "med".
2. We look at the frequency table and see that we have 2 of them (> 0).

If > 0 then deplete first match [high, med].

```
const badPoolList = [
  [wc, med],
];
```

Update frequency table:

```
freq = [
"low": 0,
"med": 1, // This one is decreased
"wc": 1,
"high": 0 // AND this one is also decreased
];
```

Repeat for fourth match:

1. Fourth element to match is "high".
2. We look at the frequency table and see that we have 0 of them.

Becuase our requency table looks like this:

```
freq = [
"low": 0,
"med": 1,
"wc": 1,
"high": 0 // IS 0
];
```

We know for sure there is no more highs left.

That's how you know if your stub is good or bad.